# Node.js Express - provide HTTP response before finish processing entire request

Tags: node.js, http, express

I have a Node.js Express server where I send the response, and then attempt to do more processing with the same request instance.

If I write to res after headers are sent, I will get an error- but what happens if I use the req readable stream after I send back the response for the corresponding response?

In other words, how can I send an HTTP response with a Node.server before I finish processing the entire request?

In *other* other words, if I already have sent back a response, how can I "consume" the request after having already sent the response - is it really just a matter of doing anything besides send back a response?

Right now, there seem to be some weird errors related to using the request object (stream) that corresponds to the response that was already sent..

Let me give some examples, with code-

the following shows the last 3 Express middleware handlers in my server. As one interesting sidenote - once one middleware handler is invoked for a request, it can't be reinvoked (it appears so). So what happens is that the first handler below gets invoked when the response is sent. Then, the other path of execution (using process.nextTick or setImmediate) calls next(), and the second two handlers are invoked, which means I end up getting a 404 logged on my server.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    var r;

    var timeRequired = (Date.now() - req.request_start) + 'ms';
    console.log("Time required for request:", timeRequired);

    if (r = req.lectalTemp) {
        if (!req.lectalSent) {
            req.lectalSent = true;
            res.status(r.status).json({timeRequired: timeRequired, success: r.data});
        }
        else {
            console.log('Headers sent already, but here is the data that would have been sent:', r);
        }
    }
    else {
        next();
    }

});


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('404: Not Found - ' + req.method + ' ' + req.originalUrl);
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {

    var timeRequired = (Date.now() - req.request_start) + 'ms';

    if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
        res.status(err.status || 500).json({
            error: 'sorry the API experienced an error serving your priority request'
        });
    }
    else {
        console.error(colors.bgRed(err), '\n', err.stack);

        if (!res.headersSent && !req.lectalSent) {
            req.lectalSent = true;
            res.status(err.status || 500).json({
                error: {
                    timeRequired: timeRequired,
                    errMessage: err.message,
                    errStack: err.stack
                }
            });
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Do you realize that if a middleware handles a response, you are not supposed to continue to call `next()` because if you keep calling `next()`, it will eventually get to your 404 handler where it will think that nothing handled the response?  There are other ways to solve that if you need other middleware to continue to process the response, but those other handlers have to make sure they do not write to the response after you've already sent the response.  You could set a flag on the request or response to indicate it's already sent the response and the others could check that flag.

Comment: yeah, that's pretty much what I have done. you can keep calling stuff and using the req stream, but I think using the res stream is probably off limits after you send the response

Comment: just FYI, the reason I ask is because, I make a simple optimization where I do a very critical DB call and then a much less critical DB call. I want to return the response after the critical call, and then have the server keep processing the less critical DB call after the response is sent, seems normal to me.

Comment: So, I don't understand what your issue is.  Just hands off the res stream after you've sent the response.  You can continue running other code on your server as long as you want and you can read from the req object all you want.  The error you speak of occurs when you try to use the res object after you've already sent the response.

Comment: yeah I guess I don't know what actions are kosher to take on the res stream and which arent after you send the response...is everything off limits or just some things..?

Comment: I asked the question, and then I figured out a solution an hour or two later..this is more of a best practice question..you can see the question if you read the original question and if you could provide a good best practice answer that might help readers who seem interested in this question/issue for which many people probably don't know what is best.

Comment: You just can't write to the response stream after you've already sent the response.  Anything else is OK.  Since most methods on the response stream are about writing or preparing to write, you should probably just avoid using the response stream after you've sent the response.

Answer (score 1):

I would have solved this with a queue. Post a message with the low critical data to a queue (eq. RabbitMq or similar) and create a worker that consume the messages in the queue asynchronously.

Comment: yeah, that's not a bad approach, we are keeping it simple and having only one api server...also the db calls are related, so I would rather have them processed by the same request for now, it's just that 1 is higher priority than the other and the client will only really care about the result of first db call. What I did was put the low priority call at the end of the I/O queue by using setImmediate() on the server, instead of using process.nextTick, which apparently is too close to synchronous for it to be useful here.

Comment: Don't know why a queue is needed here.  It sounds more like the OP just wants to continue running some more code after they've sent the response which is a perfectly fine thing to do.